# Populating spinner directly in the layout xml Error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, spinner

I'm using ActionBar Sherlock and [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).
The application have a drawer like facebook android app like this:

[image]

Once you clicked the any item in the list it check if you are registered or not, if not it will display a inflated layout (just like a dialog box) then you are required to fill it up.

I'm populating spinner inside that inflated layout.

It display properly and runs smoothly in Android Gingerbread,
But in Android jellybean it display correctly but when I clicked it crashed and forced close.

The error displayed in logcat was this:

```
11-15 10:28:36.665: D/VelocityTracker(6271): VelocityTracker: int datax = 12
11-15 10:28:36.665: D/VelocityTracker(6271): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_x = 1.200000
11-15 10:28:36.665: D/VelocityTracker(6271): VelocityTracker: int datay = 16
11-15 10:28:36.665: D/VelocityTracker(6271): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_y = 1.600000
11-15 10:28:36.758: I/SurfaceTextureClient(6271): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x53828d30, api:1, last queue time elapsed :21436 ms
11-15 10:28:36.759: I/SurfaceTextureClient(6271): [0x53828d30] frames:16, duration:21.702999, fps:0.737206
11-15 10:28:36.795: D/AbsListView(6271): checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
11-15 10:28:36.809: D/AndroidRuntime(6271): Shutting down VM
11-15 10:28:36.809: W/dalvikvm(6271): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e84908)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@417634b8 is not valid; is your activity running?
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:652)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:328)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:151)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:988)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:897)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:603)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:974)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:604)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
11-15 10:28:36.836: E/AndroidRuntime(6271):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code:

**popup_form**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"/>

                    <View 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="3dip"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray" />

                    <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Sample form"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etSPDOB"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:hint="@string/dob" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spCountry"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:entries="@array/country_array"
                            android:entryValues="@array/country_code"
                            android:prompt="@string/select_country"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnSPCancel"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Cancel"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnSPSet"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Set"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>   

</LinearLayout>
```

**array.xml**

```
<string-array name="country_array">
    <item>Australia</item>
    <item>New Zealand</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
</string-array>
```